# Malaysia 90 day stamp but with return date written under it

Tags: visas, passports, tourist-visas, malaysia

I have a short question, when I entered Malaysia I was given a 90-day stamp but my return ticket was for 1 month, the officer didn't really say anything regarding that but he did write down the return date underneath the 90 day stamp, so my question is, would it be okay for me to change the return ticket closer to the 90 days and just explain to them later that I originally intended to stay for 1 month but then decided to stay longer? because I know they had a 1-month stamp but instead he stamped 90 days for me. I hope you can help me with this question.

Comment: It is always best to stay with your original plans. (I am not sure Malaysia minds but many countries do.) You can always make plans to come back.

Comment: Is there an Immigration office where you are staying where you can go to check this out before you change your travel plan?

Comment: What country is your passport from?

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify. Putting on hold.

Answer (score 0):

The entry stamp in your passport indicates how many days (including the arrival date) that you are allowed to legally stay  in the country.

You could stay 90 minutes or 90 days, it's 100% up to you.  You do not need to inform anyone at immigration of anything. You just leave like you normally would.

Comment: I answered the question accurately based on my personal experience entering/leaving Malaysia.  I wonder how much experience the downvoter has?

Comment: I suspect that the downvote may be related to lack of sources or details of experience. For example, it would be relevant if you have actually stayed 90 days with an earlier departure date under the stamp. A little background would greatly improve your answer.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan He needs to know if he can stay up to the 90 days he has permission for, and if he needs to notify immigration.    The answer is no.   Sorry I do not have a link to Malay immigration website.